# PHP function in the same page

Tags: javascript, php, html, post, web-applications

I propose you my following problem: I would like to make sure that the textbox (which appears and disappears according to the radioButton choice) is used to receive a data that will be used to perform a mkdir ...
Let me explain better the case that the value of the txtBox is "Hello" when I press the button (submit) must automatically create a folder (via mkdir) and must redirect to the address contained in the function javascript controll () ..

I want to understand if it is possible to have everything on the same page and not having to create other pages for PHP

this is one of my attempts .. but it does not work :(

```html
<html>

<body>

<fieldset>
    <strong>Did you want to insert another ?</strong>
    <form action="test()" method="POST" name="prova" onsubmit="return controlla();">
        YES<input type="radio" name="scelta" value="yes" />
  <input type="text" id="myInput" style="display: none;"><br>
  NO<input type="radio" name="scelta" value="no" /><br />

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</fieldset>
<script language="javascript">
    function controlla() {
        console.log("oie");
        x = document.prova;
        if (x.scelta.value == "yes") {
            window.location.href = '../affidatario.php?idCantiere=<?php echo $idCantiere?>'
            return false;
        }
        if (x.scelta.value == "no") {
            alert("NO");
            window.location.href = '../inserimentoCantiere.php'
            return false;
        }
    }
    document.querySelectorAll('input[name="scelta"').forEach(function(a) {
        a.addEventListener("change", function() {
            let textBox = document.getElementById("myInput");
            if (textBox) textBox.style.display = this.value === "yes" ? "block" : "none";
        })
    });
</script>
<?php 

function test(){
  $var = $_POST["myInput"];

if(mkdir("prova/".$date."_".$var.'/Mezzi di Trasporto'))
{
echo "DirectoryCreated";
}
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$var');</script>";
}

?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please clean-up your code, and use English only so that we may understand the flow of your logic better.

Comment: clean-up and changed to english :) @Ahmad

Comment: You could create a template PHP page that will be copied to each new directory you create.

Comment: what sorry ? :O

Answer (score -1):

Maybe by doing redirection directly in PHP ?
Be careful, my solution (untested) uses header, you have to be sure there is no data sent to client before !

```
<html>

<body>

<fieldset>
    <strong>Did you want to insert another ?</strong>
    <form action="#" method="POST" name="prova">
        YES<input type="radio" name="scelta" value="yes" />
        <input type="text" id="myInput" style="display: none;"><br>
        NO<input type="radio" name="scelta" value="no" /><br />

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</fieldset>
<script language="javascript">

    document.querySelectorAll('input[name="scelta"').forEach(function(a) {
        a.addEventListener("change", function() {
            let textBox = document.getElementById("myInput");
            if (textBox) textBox.style.display = this.value === "yes" ? "block" : "none";
        })
    });
</script>
<?php 

function test(){
  $var = $_POST["myInput"];

if(mkdir("prova/".$date."_".$var.'/Mezzi di Trasporto'))
{

//Header redirection
header('Location: ../affidatario.php?idCantiere='+ $idCantiere);
} else {
header('Location: ../inserimentoCantiere.php');
}

//Call the function if there is an input :
if(isset($_POST["myInput"])){
test();
}
?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I did not understand ... could you be clearer?

Comment: In your code, i don't see the call of test() function

Comment: i put it on the form action="test()"

Comment: Oh i see, action="test()" is trying to find page 'test()'. You have to call the function in PHP, not HTML/JS (you can't call directly a PHP function with client-side language such as HTML)

Comment: damnation I was not aware of it .. do you have any solution to propose?

Comment: As I said before, you can test if $_POST["myInput"] exists (with isset function) and if it exists, just call your test() function in PHP code

Comment: `<?php 

function test(){
  $var = $_POST["myInput"];

if(mkdir("prova/".$date."_".$var.'/Mezzi di Trasporto'))
{
echo "DirectoryCreated";
}
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$var');</script>";
}
if(isset($_POST["myInput"])){ test();}

?>`

Comment: would it be like that?

Comment: Are you sure that your test() function is executed ? Could you echo something (comment your directory creation script)

Comment: if I notice, I have an alert that should show me the content of $nomeAffidatario = $_POST["myInput"];

Comment: If you print an echo at the 1st line of test function and this is not displayed, so the function is not called... I will try your code

Comment: You can try to do redirection directly in PHP, and your form need to call current page http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Man sorry but i can understand you .. could you edit the code of your answer with the changes you are proposing to me?