# $_POST problems with PHP & HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, post, get

I have a problem with the following `$_POST`. As you see from the code once the radioButton has value *YES* and you press submit you are redirected to the page where I put  `"IdCantiere" = (value random)` and? `myInput =` which would be the `$_POST` that does not work for me.
The redirect refers to the *affidatario.php* page in which I make the `$_GET` of both variables.

executing a `var_dump($_GET)` the only thing that finds is idCantiere. How can I get the value of myInput?

I place my code and some screens

```html
<html>

<body>

<fieldset>
    <strong>Vuoi inserire un affidatario?</strong>
    <form action="../affidatario.php?idCantiere=<?php echo $idCantiere?>" method="POST" name="prova" onsubmit="return controlla();">
        SI<input type="radio" name="scelta" value="si" />
   <label name="myLabel" id="myLabel" style="display: none;">Ragione Sociale Affidataria</label><input type="text" id="myInput" style="display: none;"><br>
  NO<input type="radio" name="scelta" value="no" /><br />

        <button type="submit">INVIA</button>
    </form>
</fieldset>
<?php 

$myInput=$_POST["myInput"];


?>
<script language="javascript">
   function controlla() {
        console.log("oie");
        x = document.prova;
        if (x.scelta.value == "si") {
            window.location.href = '../affidatario.php?idCantiere=<?php echo $idCantiere?>?myInput=<?php echo $myInput?>'
            return false;
        }
        if (x.scelta.value == "no") {
            alert("Hai risposto no");
            window.location.href = '../inserimentoCantiere.php'
            return false;
        }
    }
 
    document.querySelectorAll('input[name="scelta"').forEach(function(a) {
        a.addEventListener("change", function() {
            let textBox = document.getElementById("myLabel");
            if (textBox) textBox.style.display = this.value === "si" ? "block" : "none";
        })
    });
     document.querySelectorAll('input[name="scelta"').forEach(function(a) {
        a.addEventListener("change", function() {
            let textBox = document.getElementById("myInput");
            if (textBox) textBox.style.display = this.value === "si" ? "block" : "none";
        })
    });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

```html
<?php 

 $idCantiere = $_GET["idCantiere"];
 date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
 chdir("../../../../../Archivio/Cantieri");
 opendir(".");
  $myInput = $_GET["myInput"];

 if(mkdir("../../../../Archivio/Cantieri/".$date."_".$myInput))
 {
 echo "Cartella account creata con successo! :D";
 }
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(myInput);</script>";

var_dump($_GET);
 session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
     header('location: ../../../index.php');
    }
    else
    {
 
?>
```

var_dump
[image: Var_DUMP]

Comment: I do not know if it's the correct answer, but, if I'm not mistaken, $ _POST must be used with 'name' not with 'id'

Comment: `$ MyInput = $ _ POST [ 'myInput "];` I think it's empty

Comment: it's not very clear..you set $myinput with post, but when you edit your input $_POST remain empty.. so you have to retrieve this value in your js file or retrieve it directly from $_POST in your affidatario.php file

Comment: [Didn't you post something like this already?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53494554/1415724) - Seems like a form of repost.

Comment: yes but if you read the questions you understand that the project is the same, while the questions are different !!! @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: so this is an undefined index question then

Comment: So @AlexLogic read the value in the affidatario.php the value $_POST["myInput"] and read how $_GET and $_POST works

Comment: Do you ever actually send the form? Your function controlla simply loads a new page by setting window.location.href

Comment: _“How can I get the value of myInput?”_ - by _sending_ it correctly in the first place. Did it not make you think, that in your debug output, the value of `idCantiere` was shown as `2053813695?myInput=` …? That’s because you messed up the query string syntax - it _starts_ with a question mark, but multiple name=value pairs are separated from each other by an ampersand (whereas you tried to use a _second_ question mark.)

Comment: I'm sorry that I made so many mistakes but I'm a beginner and I do not understand where I'm wrong ...

Comment: @misorude so I should put something like this =  `../affidatario.php?idCantiere=<?php echo $idCantiere?>&myInput=<?php echo $myInput?> `

Comment: Yes, of course. That’s how a query string works.

Comment: okay now the result of vardump is    `array(2) { ["idCantiere"]=> string(9) "867012990" ["myInput"]=> string(0) "" }`

Comment: but i don't understand why the fileds is NULL

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner but why did you put me as a duplicate? what does that have to do with my question? * Confused *

Answer (score 0):

First, use `name` as well as id for your input tag:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" name="myInput" ...
```

When the form is sent, you can read the value using `$_POST["myInput"]`.

Second, your `controlla` function that decides whether to send the form always returns `false`. This means the form is actually never sent. Changing `window.location.href` takes the user to a new page, but without sending the form data to the server.

It looks like your intention is to change the URL where the form is sent. To do that, you can change the form's `action`:

```
    function controlla(form) {
        console.log("oie");
        x = document.prova;
        if (x.scelta.value == "si") {
            return true;
        }
        if (x.scelta.value == "no") {
            alert("Hai risposto no");
            form.action = '../inserimentoCantiere.php'
            return true;
        }
    }
```

For this to work you have to change the onsubmit event handler so that it passes the form to `controlla`:

```
    <form ...... onsubmit="return controlla(this);">
```

Comment: Hello Joni thanks for the reply .. I added name but despite this I do not work the $ _POST :(

Comment: Yes you have a problem in the controlla function too. I'd delete this answer for now but the mobile app doesn't have that function

Comment: and how can i modify controlla() function?

Comment: see the update,